# Retrieving a sum of a column with group by clause in LARAVEL

Tags: sql, laravel

I am new to laravel and I want to write the below SQL in **LARAVEL** format.

```
SELECT user, SUM(total_net_amount) AS total 
FROM primary_invoices  
GROUP BY user_id
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That `DESC` shouldn't be there. (It belongs to ORDER BY.)

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. do `GROUP BY user` here.

Comment: Can you show us your own Laravel code attempt?

Comment: You have an answer but these links will help a lot moving forward: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries and https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exact answer i was looking for. I hope this will help someone else.

```
$report_dates = DB::table('primary_invoices')
->select('user','datee', DB::raw('SUM(total_net_amount) as total'))
->where(function ($query) use($date_value,$enddate_value) {
$query->whereBetween('datee', [$date_value, $enddate_value]);
})
->where('user',$search_value)
->groupBy('datee')
->orderBy('datee','asc')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PrimaryInvoice::selectRaw('SUM(total_net_amount) as total')
   ->groupBy('user_id')
   ->get()
```

If primary_invoices has a relation with the users table, then you can use something like this:

```
PrimaryInvoice::selectRaw('SUM(total_net_amount) as total, user_id')
   ->with('user')
   ->groupBy('user_id')
   ->get()
```